# Retrieving array of checkboxes and select boxes from view with controller (grails)

Tags: grails

I am looking at some old code and am trying to reach the goal of Attaching the contact instance ID that is selected (checkbox) with the reports to select box that would be populated with the remote field. For instance, this is the params passed to the controller:

> [id:1, reportsToResults:[x, y, z, ], reportsTo.id:[56, 55, 55],
>   reportsTo:[id:[56, 55, 55]], contactList:[55, 57], _contactList:[, , ,
>   ], _select:, action:index, controller:tempController]

What I theoretically need is something that is as such:

```
contactList:[ , , 55, 57, ] (where empty spaces are checkboxes that are NOT selected.    
reportsTo.id:[ , , 56, 56, ] (where empty spaces are empty selection boxes.
```

How can I pass the array of values? Because I can pass all the contactList IDs and the reportsTo.id - but I cannot match them up correctly based on array slot or tying them together.

Any idea:?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="company-roster" class="company-roster">
        <h1>${companyName} Roster</h1>
            <g:form>
                <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${id}" />
                <div class="choicePanel">
                    <div class="choicePanel-reportsTo">
                        <label>Save all reports to additions:</label>
                        <g:actionSubmit value="Update Reports To" action="addReportsTo"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script>
                    function all() {
                        $(':checkbox[name=select]').click (function () {
                          $(':checkbox[name=contactList]').prop('checked', this.checked);
                        });            
                    }
                </script>
                <div style="position:absolute; margin-top:10px; width: 1350px; height: 650px; overflow: auto;">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><g:checkBox name="select" onclick="all();"/></th>
                            <g:sortableColumn property="firstName" action="roster" title="${message(code: 'contact.firstName.label', default: 'First Name')}" />
                            <g:sortableColumn property="lastName" action="roster" title="${message(code: 'contact.lastName.label', default: 'Last Name')}" />
                            <th>Reports To</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <g:each in="${companyRoster}" status="i" var="contactInstance">
                                <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">

                                <td><g:checkBox name="contactList" value="${contactInstance.id}" checked="${false}"/></td>
                                <td>${fieldValue(bean: contactInstance, field: "firstName")}</td>
                                <td>${fieldValue(bean: contactInstance, field: "lastName")}</td>
                                <td>
                                    Reports To: <g:remoteField action="getReportsToResults" controller="contact" id="" update="rtResult_${contactInstance.id}" paramName="search" name="reportsToResults" value="" />
                                    <br/>
                                    <g:each in ="${contactInstance?.reportsTo}" var="reportsTo" status="x">
                                        <li style="list-style-type:none;">${reportsTo}<g:link controller="contact" action="removeReportsTo" params="${[reportsToID: reportsTo.id, contactInstanceID: contactInstance.id, comp_id:id]}">Remove</g:link></li>
                                    </g:each>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div id="rtResult_${contactInstance.id}" class="rtResult_${contactInstance.id}">
                                        <g:select name="reportsTo.id" from="${rtResults}" value="" />
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                        </g:each>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
            </g:form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually do this by giving each check box on the form a unique and identifiable name as well as the corresponding id that it references in a `hiddenField` like...

```
<g:checkBox name="contact.${i}.checkBox" checked="${false}"/>
<g:hiddenField name="contact.${i}.id" value="${contactInstance.id}" />
```

Above, i used the `i` variable from the `g:each` loop which will ensure that each will be in sequence and unique.

Next, you'll need to store the number of items in the `g:form` so your controller action knows how many checkBox params to look for, like so (out side of the g:each but in the `g:form`)....

```
<g:hiddenField name="contactCount" value="${companyRoster.size()}" />
```

Finally, you can iterate through the `params` map and deal with those that are selected or not selected.

```
def doStuff = {
    def contactCount = params.contactCount.toInteger();

    for( i in 0..contactCount){


        def contact = Contact.get(params.contact."${i}".id);

        if (params.contact."${i}".checkBox){ //<-- this will return 'on' or ''
            println("you selected: ${contact}");
        }else{
            println("you DID NOT select: ${contact}");
        }

    }
}
```

There are a couple ways to deal with this but the above solution is the way I've always done it.  The code is not tested for syntax and just off the top of my head but, hopefully you get the idea.  Enjoy!

Comment: I tried to do the same for radio type input with name='inputName', but when i tried to follow your way, it failed because somehow it didn't recognize the input name name='inputName.${i}', and the error message stating that inputName cannot be null. Any idea on how to make it work for radio type input?